# Simple LINQ question about Any()

Tags: linq

I wanna write a linq query to do this

```
Select id from selectedBrands 
where name='Nick' or name='Matt'
```

is this linq correct????

```
  var brandsToNotShow=new[] {"Nick","Matt"};
    model.Names=

                    (from s in selectedBrands
                    where  brandsToNotShow.Any()
                    select s.Brand.name
                ).ToList();
```

where model.Names is a List

Comment: What is the Linq query supposed to do? As such it looks OK, but without knowing what you want to do, it is difficult to tell.

Comment: The initial query seems like you want to select the IDs for the brands "Nick" and "Matt".  However, the linq query makes it seem like you want to select the NAMES of all brands EXCEPT "Nick" and "Matt".  Which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not correct.

```
brandsNotToShow.Any()
```

asks "are there any elements of this list", the answer to which is, yes, there are two elements.

This query is probably closer to what you want:

```
 from s in selectedBrands
 where brandsNotToShow.Contains(s.Brand.Name)
 select s.Brand.Name
```

(actually, if it's brands **NOT** to show, it might be

```
where !brandsNotToShow.Contains(s.Brand.Name)
```

I can't tell from your example)

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN Any():

> Determines whether any element of a
>   sequence satisfies a condition.

So in your example `Any` just checks to see if there are any items in brandsToNotSHow.

You probably want something like this:

```
from s in selectedBrands
where brantsToNotShow.Contains (s.Brand.Name)
SELECT s.Brand.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say what you want based on your choice of variable names, but the literal LINQ version of your SQL is

```
from brand in selectedBrands
where brand.name == 'Nick' || brand.name == 'Matt'
select brand.id;
```

If you had an array or sequnce in your code, you could use `Contains`

```
from brand in selectedBrands
where nameSequence.Contains(brand.name)
select brand.id;
```

But if that sequence is sizable, it is probably best to just join to the sequence.

```
from brand in selectedBrands
join name in nameSequence on brand.name equals name
select brand.id;
```